# "Allow Full Access" for custom keyboard causes sigkill, device freezes up

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

Switching "Allow Full Access" to ON in my custom keyboard's settings is causing a sigkill in the parent app, and the whole device to sort of lock up.

I can access the home screen, but tapping on any app icon doesn't do anything, except the app icon gets "stuck" as appearing highlighted. Restarting the device fixes this, and then the keyboard is useable and everything appears to be back to normal.

From searching around it appears that the sigkill is expected (the app is supposed to restart with the new "allow full access" setting, from what I understand), but the device locking up is what I'm worried about.

This is happenings on a physical iPhone 6s+ and the 6s+ simulator. Xcode version 7.3 (beta).

Comment: Please post crash logs if you have them.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

While you are on debug mode and changing keyboards Full Access, it will cause the crash of extension but while you are release it will work just fine, please check it and give a follow up.